# confusionMatrix for logistic regression in R

Tags: r, validation, logistic-regression, confusion-matrix

I want to calculate two confusion matrix for my logistic regression using my training data and my testing data:

```
logitMod <- glm(LoanStatus_B ~ ., data=train, family=binomial(link="logit"))
```

i set the threshold of predicted probability at 0.5:

```
confusionMatrix(table(predict(logitMod, type="response") >= 0.5,
                      train$LoanStatus_B == 1))
```

And the the code below works well for my training set.
However, when i use the test set:

```
confusionMatrix(table(predict(logitMod, type="response") >= 0.5,
                      test$LoanStatus_B == 1))
```

it gave me an error of

```
Error in table(predict(logitMod, type = "response") >= 0.5, test$LoanStatus_B == : all arguments must have the same length
```

Why is this? How can I fix this? Thank you!

Comment: you need to  pass the test dataset to the predict function, otherwise it will make predictions on the train dataset. ie `predict(logitMod, newdata=test, type="response")`

Comment: Thx it works!..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think there is a problem with the use of predict, since you forgot to provide the new data. Also, you can use the function `confusionMatrix` from the `caret` package to compute and display confusion matrices, but you don't need to table your results before that call.

Here, I created a toy dataset that includes a representative binary target variable and then I trained a model similar to what you did.

```
train <- data.frame(LoanStatus_B = as.numeric(rnorm(100)>0.5), b= rnorm(100), c = rnorm(100), d = rnorm(100))
logitMod <- glm(LoanStatus_B ~ ., data=train, family=binomial(link="logit"))
```

Now, you can predict the data (for example, your training set) and then use `confusionMatrix()` that takes two arguments:

- your predictions
- the observed classes

```
library(caret)
# Use your model to make predictions, in this example newdata = training set, but replace with your test set    
pdata <- predict(logitMod, newdata = train, type = "response")

# use caret and compute a confusion matrix
confusionMatrix(data = as.numeric(pdata>0.5), reference = train$LoanStatus_B)
```

Here are the results

```
Confusion Matrix and Statistics

          Reference
Prediction  0  1
         0 66 33
         1  0  1

               Accuracy : 0.67            
                 95% CI : (0.5688, 0.7608)
    No Information Rate : 0.66            
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 0.4625
```

Comment: What is this line doing data = as.numeric(pdata>0.5)

Comment: Your target variable is either 0 or 1, but the prediction returns a value in the range 0 to 1. Therefore you need to convert it to binary (discretization). For example, you test if a value is bigger or smaller than 0.5. TRUE is then converted to 1 (and FALSE to 0) using as.nmeric

Comment: So it is the threshold, right? I can change it into any 0-1 number i want

Comment: The last line in the result is "'Positive' Class : 0  ", but in my case i want positive class:1, which is default, can i do that?

Comment: 0.5 is the threshold. You are supposed to use the number that best fits your data. 0.5 is a pretty consistent number to start from.

Comment: Sure you can do. The function has an argument for that. Please, check `?confusionMatrix()`. For example: `confusionMatrix(data = as.numeric(pdata>0.5), reference = train$LoanStatus_B, positive = "1")`

Comment: Okay, but here the 1 is a numeric instead of string right?

Comment: In this case, "1" corresponds to your numeric 1s. However, the positive argument is provided as a character! If you care about accuracy, it doesn't matter. But it is important for computing sensitivity/specificity, cause you need to know which are true/false positives. Fore example, try: `confusionMatrix(data = as.factor(c("A","B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B")), reference = as.factor(c("A","A", "A", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "A")), positive = "A")` and the same line with `positive = "B"`. I hope this was useful. If so, please, validate my answer. Thanks